# command not found when script run inside another process

Tags: shell-script, permissions, path, background-process

This is running in qBittorrent, as a completion script.  When the download is complete, I want this script to run and ship off all the files to a remote server.

The script, when run from terminal manually works.   When it runs as part of the app I get this:

```
  21   │ PATH is: 
  22   │ /app/bin:/usr/bin
  23   │ + /usr/bin/rsync --recursive -vv --remove-source-files --exclude temp <... etc.>
  24   │ /<path>/onDownloadComplete.sh: line 49: /usr/bin/rsync: No such file or directory
```

When I run this in the terminal, it finds rsync. (same with `which rsync`)

`ls -lah /usr/bin | grep rsync`

However in my script I'm echoing the results of `ls -lah /usr/bin` and rsync is NOT in there, but a bunch of others are.

So, somehow, the process, running as `bswift` - can not find a command in `/usr/bin` that I can find.

Why is this?  I've thought about checking SE Linux, doesn't seem to be the case.

Also, all of this is running in a code block like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
{
## Code 

} 2>&1 | /usr/bin/tee -a /home/bswift/src/qbittorrent-completion-scripts/run_log.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

Check the permissions of the /usr/bin/rsync against the permissions/ownership of onDownloadComplete.sh.

While running "manually", you may be running as root or different user who has permissions to execute rsync on your system.

```
ls -l /usr/bin/rsync
ls -l /<path>/onDownloadComplete.sh
```

Compare the owner and group fields of <onDownloadComplete.sh> to the rw permissions of rsync.

Additionally, check if the owner user of the onDownloadComplete.sh is included in the Group of rsync.
You may need to add the Owner/User of <onDownloadComplete.sh> to the Group of rsync.

Option 2:
Check the pathing inside the script. See if it contains /usr/bin

```
echo $PATH
```

Comment: rsync permissions: 

`-rwxr-xr-x 1 root  /usr/bin/rsync*`

script permissions: 

`-rwxrwxrwx 1 bswift onDownloadComplete.sh*`

I've created a group called `bsautomation` and granted access to files via visudo.  I think this should have worked but doesn't seem to. 

```
cat /etc/sudoers.d/bsautomation
                                                                                                  
`%bsautomation ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/rsync`
```

Comment: also - there is no 'group' rsync that i can see.    PATH = `/app/bin:/usr/bin`.  That's why I'm confused because /usr/bin is in the path,   and if the script does `ls /usr/bin` it doesn't see rsync

Comment: I did a chown bswift on rsync, and chmod 777 just to see if the sledge hammer works and it doesn't. :(